# Can NVidia GeForce 1080 support 3 screens with one 4K and two HD?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

The GeForce 1080 is already a bit old nowadays, but I have been using it for years with 3 HD screens, of which one is pivoted in portrait mode. (Resolution of each screen is 1920x1200, an 8:5 ratio.)

I am thinking of changing the middle screen to a 4K screen, which will give me a bit more room on the screens. For this to work I'm probably rotating the right screen also with 90 degrees, simply because it otherwise won't fit on my desk :D

Now the question is... will my current video card, the Asus GeForce 1080, support this configuration or will I get a laggy experience? I know 3x 4K is too much, but will this card manage 1x 4K + 2xFHD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes. From the Full Specs area at [Nvidia GTX 1080](https://www.nvidia.com/en-sg/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1080/)

```
Display Support:
Maximum Digital Resolution     7680x4320@60Hz
Standard Display Connectors    DP 1.43, HDMI 2.0b, DL-DVI 
Multi Monitor                  Yes 
HDCP                           2.2
```

There is a caveat on the digital resolution that states

> 7680x4320 at 60 Hz RGB 8-bit with dual DisplayPort connectors or 7680x4320 at 60 Hz YUV420 8-bit with one DisplayPort 1.3 connector

So in theory each DisplayPort connector should be able to output 4K at least, potentially up to 8K with lower colour fidelity (RGB vs YUV420). The total pixel count of 8K (7680x4320) will be higher than 1x4K and 2xFullHD screens.

So long as you have enough connectors then you should be fine. I'd be tempted to run the 4K monitor off the DisplayPort output if possible.

Comment: That's what I thought, though I'm curious if the performance of the card will actually be enough to manage this at a reasonable frame rate. My current setup is basically "3k", when I replace this it will be "6k" which is roughly twice the amount of pixels.

Comment: For just pushing 2D screens it should be more than enough. There is some basic 3D work in doing desktop compositing, but it is nowhere near as bad as modern gaming.